# Need information regarding publishing a double variable on to a ROS topic

Tags: c++, ros

I am using ROS to publish **double** variables on to a ROS topic. This topic will be advertising the topic so that any subscribers can access the data. 
The following is the code which I have used to publish the data:

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher Auc_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("/auc", 1000);
std_msgs::Float64 areaValue;

areaValue.data.push_back(Area)
Auc_pub.publish(areaValue);
```

Here **Area** is the **double** variable which I need to publish it over the topic **/auc**. I am not able to build this file as don't know how to enter the **Area** variable into the **areaValue**.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`std_msgs::Float64`](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Float64.html), it shows that it contains a single data field, which is called `data` and will be of type `double` in C++.

So, in your code, you just do:

```
areaValue.data = Area
```

assuming that `Area` is a `double`.

I suggest that you take a look at the basic [*Writing a simple Publisher and Subscriber*](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c++%29) tutorial on the ROS wiki.

**EDIT**

If what is in the original post is the entirety of your code, then it's probably not going to do exactly what you think it does. If you use the default constructor for a `publisher`, messages `published` on them are emitted once immediately. Any nodes `subscribed` to that topic at the moment of publishing will get the message, and then the topic will be clear. If you want any node that `subscribes` to the topic to receive the last message published on it, do the following:

```
ros::Publisher Auc_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("/auc", 1000, true);
```

That last bool `true` tells the `publisher` that it should [*latch*](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options) messages that are published.

But you have yet another problem, presuming this is all your code: You never [spin](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Single-threaded_Spinning), so your node starts up, `advertises` its topic, publishes one message on it, and then shuts down, taking the topic with it (assuming nothing was `subscribed` to the topic). You need to add the following before the end of your `main`:

```
ros::spin();
```

This will keep the node active (and thus the topic alive) until `ros::ok()` returns `false`, I.E. until the node is killed.

Of course, your message is still only going to be published once, but the topic will at least stay alive. If you want the message to be broadcast periodically, use a [`ros::Timer`](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) and put the `pulish` call inside the timer's callback.

But seriously, please read the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), they'll walk you through all of this stuff.

Comment: I changed the **area.Value.data=Area**. There was no error in buliding the code but, I still cannot find the published topic. I tried to check it using **rosnode list** couldn't find the topic either.

Comment: Or you might use ros::spinOnce() in a loop like

 `while (ros::ok()) 
{ 
  /* your code here */

    ros::spinOnce();
}`

Comment: @ave Sure, but only if you need to do processing in a non-deterministic loop. Otherwise it's better to just use a ``Timer``, do your loop processing in the callback for the timer, and ``spin()``.

Comment: @aruisdante I included `ros::spinOnce()` and I tried running `rostopic echo /evaluation/auc` and I only get the published data once or sometimes never (in that case I have to end `rostopic echo` and restart it ). I rarely get a series of ouputs through the [rostopic echo]. I don't understand is there something worng  in the way I am publishing the data ?

Comment: As I said, you're only publishing it once. If you want it to be published more than once, you need to use a ``ros::Timer``, or call publish from some other loop. Seriously, please read the tutorials I linked to. They will really help you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution for the problem. I had multiple    ros:spinOnce() in the code. And also in the snippet

```
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Publisher Auc_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("/auc", 1000);
std_msgs::Float64 areaValue;

areaValue.data;
Auc_pub.publish(areaValue);
```

The publisher **Auc_pub** was created and destroyed ( As I had included the publisher in a function... my bad). Instead, i included the publisher in the **main function** where the publisher is created only once and stays alive until the execution completes. And, thanks to @aruisdante your suggestion helped.